# Sorting out tags about pictures

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

So we've got:

[illustrations](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illustrations) — 29 questions — created Dec 14 '15, first asked Nov 21 '10

> Worth a thousand words
>
> Questions about using images in a work. How to find an illustrator,
>   how to work with one, how to illustrate one's own work. Also covers
>   graphic novels, comics, and children's picture books.

[images](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) — 14 questions — created Apr 11 '18, first asked Jun 14 '13

> This tag should be used for questions about the usage of images in
>   writing, such as when writing a report, thesis or user documentation.
>
> This tag should be used for questions about the usage of images in
>   writing, such as when writing a report, thesis or user documentation.
>   You might want to add information about your mode of writing, such as
>   [technical-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing) or [academic-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing). This tag can also be used for
>   questions about [tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) and [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) that are related to images in
>   writing.

[book-cover](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-cover) — 3 questions — first asked Feb 13 '16 — no wiki

[picture-books](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picture-books) — 1 question — first asked Jan 28 '19 — no wiki

[plotting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) — 9 questions — created Apr 27 '18, first asked Feb 6 '14

> This tag should be used for questions about plotting as a technical
>   term used for the graphical representation of a data set, such as
>   questions about tools or software that can assist you in visualizing
>   the plot of your fictional novel.
>
> This tag should be used for questions about plotting as a technical
>   term used for the graphical representation of a data set, such as
>   questions about [tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) or [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) that can assist you in visualizing
>   the [plot](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) of your [fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction)al [novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel).

[diagrams](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) — 5 questions — created Apr 20 '18, first asked Aug 18 '11

> This tag should be used for questions about the usage of diagrams in
>   your writing.
>
> This tag should be used for questions about the usage of diagrams in
>   your writing. For example if you are interested in [technique](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique)s or [rules](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules)
>   about positioning diagrams in your [technical-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing).

[screenshots](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenshots) — 2 questions — created Mar 8 '18, first asked Aug 31 '11

> This tag should be used for questions about screenshots in a written
>   piece of work, for example in training documentation.
>
> This tag should be used for questions about screenshots in a written
>   piece of work, for example in training documentation. You should
>   mention whether you are focusing for example on [academic-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing) or
>   [technical-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing) and if you would like information about [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) to
>   make or keep track of the screenshots or for example want to integrate
>   them into your [user-guides](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-guides) in [microsoft-word](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word).

---

I see two basic divisions here:

1. Artwork.  Illustrations and book cover and things we don't have tags for: art,  drawings, photos, logos, etc.
2. Graphics (technical/data).  Images, diagrams, screenshots, plotting.

Both groups can have questions about creating the image, working with someone to create the image, using the image, and so on.

I am open to either merging everything into one tag or keeping it as two main tags (leaning towards the latter).  And maybe having 1-2 main tags plus a couple extras if desired.  But I frankly think it makes no sense to have things like [screenshots](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenshots) and [diagrams](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) when we don't even have tags for art or photography.

**Can we do some synonyms, merging, re-tagging, and wiki cleanup?**

---

The outlier is [picture-books](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picture-books), which I included because it was tagged for a question about a painting (off topic and closed and I removed the tag) and because it does deal with pictures.  Though so does [comics](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics), which I didn't include and would keep.  I'm fine with [picture-books](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picture-books), though it needs its other side, [chapter-books](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chapter-books), which doesn't exist.  Both of which are part of [children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children)

---

UPDATE: [graphics](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) and [artwork](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artwork) have been created with wiki guidance added.  All retagging, merging, synonym addition, etc is done.  Thank you moderators!  See comments under answers for details.

Answer (score 4):

I whole-heartedly support [artwork](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artwork) and [graphics](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics).

I am also in favour of merging everything else into them, since that avoids the "noise" that retagging makes.

[plotting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) is an exception: while its usage guide points towards one thing, it's actual usage, in all the questions it's been applied to, has been synonymous to [plot](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot). So that's where the questions should be merged into.

Comment: Yeah, I know we already discussed [plot] and [plotting] and I agree with you.  It's too confusing (even with wiki) to keep [plotting] anyway.

Comment: Do we punt [book-cover]?

Comment: [book-cover] is [artwork]. It has only three questions, so it doesn't appear that a lot of people need it.

Comment: I'm fine with that, but we did discuss it briefly before.  Sometimes a tag is important even if it's rarely used.

Comment: Fair point. I think I've made that point myself in the past. I donno - does anybody else have an opinion one way or the other?

Comment: I suspect that book *covers* have some special considerations that don't apply to internal illustrations.  Let's keep the tag for now, even if all the questions are also tagged [artwork].  If we decide to drop [book-covers] later that's easy to do, but if we decide we wanted it after all, it'd be more work to find those few questions.

Comment: I agree with @MonicaCellio that book covers aren't *just* artwork, and that we should keep [tag:book-covers] for the time being. It probaby would benefit from a brief description, though. For a contrived example of a book-covers question that wouldn't be covered by artwork, consider choice of paper to use for a book cover for a paperback book.

Comment: @aCVn other examples of book-cover questions: text layout around the graphic, placement of testimonials (or not), use of "extras" like shiny gold or embossing.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Some of those may be better off on [graphicsdesign.se], but I stand by my agreement that the set of [tag:book-covers] questions differs from the set of [tag:artwork] questions, even if there is some potential overlap.

Answer (score 3):

I created [artwork](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artwork)

> Drawings, paintings, photographs, and other art meant to illustrate
>   writing.  Use this tag for questions about the actual art used in
>   novels, comics, or other written or scripted works, about finding or
>   working with artists, or about incorporating illustrations in your
>   writing.  For questions about depictions of data in a graphical form, use [graphics] instead.

And [graphics](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics)

> For questions about depictions of data in a graphical form.  Graphs,
>   plots, diagrams, charts, screenshots, and other images used in
>   scientific or technical writing or other nonfiction.  For questions
>   about drawings, paintings, photographs, and other art meant to
>   illustrate writing, use [artwork] instead.

---

I have only put each new tag on one question.  Let's discuss which tags to make synonyms, which to merge, and which to keep.  Then Monica or another moderator should make changes so we don't flood the homepage with retagging efforts.

Comment: I have retagged two questions under [tag:illustrations] that were a better fit for [tag:graphics]. The rest can be merged into [tag:artwork]. (Of those two, one was rather borderline - about guitar chords. It is "specific information in coded form" rather than "a pretty picture that's related to what's written" though, so graphics seemed a better fit.)

Comment: [tag:images] has a mix of both. It would have to be done manually. Slowly, so as not to flood the active page.

Comment: There's at least one question that would fit under [tag:book-cover], it is about book cover, but it has five other tags already ([tag:illustarions] and [tag:publishing] included). Not sure what to do about it.

Comment: [tag:diagrams] and [tag:screenshots] can be safely merged into [tag:graphics]. I suppose the tag info for [graphics] should also include screenshots.

Comment: This sounds great!

Comment: @Galastel great work thanks.  I already have "screenshots" as an example under [graphics].

Comment: @Galastel I agree that the guitar chords question fits better under graphics.  The OP even calls it "diagrams."  Now, if the OP's book also had pretty pictures of people playing guitars, and the question was about both types of pictures, it could use both tags.

Comment: I retagged 3 questions with the tag [images], including the one I added [graphics] to yesterday.  How slow is slow enough?  There are only 11 left to retag.

Comment: I've now retagged everything under [tag:images] except for one closed and one duplicate question.  I don't know how to do that without putting them in the reopen queue.  @MonicaCellio or another moderator, can you retag the last two questions and delete [tag:images]?  Everything there belongs in [tag:artwork] or [tag:graphics] (or in one case, both).  Thanks!

Comment: @Cyn Only questions in "on hold" status are automatically nominated for reopen review upon edit. Questions that are "closed" require a reopen vote to be entered into the reopen review queue.

Comment: @aCVn Ahhh...  Okay, I've done the last two edits.  The [tag:images] tag is now unused.  Can we delete it now?  (given how confusing it was...one of those questions used it to mean imagery, I'm not sure it deserves to be a synonym).  Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, it's easier for a moderator to do a merge than to edit every question.  We can create the synonyms at the same time.  I think we're going to want some of these synonyms (like screenshots) because people will create them again otherwise.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Oh Galastel and I saved bunches of that for you.  We only retagged where there was ambiguity.  [illustrations] is ready for you to merge with [artwork] ( I think it makes sense to keep illustrations as a synonym).  Diagrams and screenshots are ready to merge into graphics. [images] was all over the map and is now cleared out and and ready to delete.  We haven't yet done [plotting] but it can be deleted after it's retagged manually (not able to be merged because the tag is used for a lot of things).

Comment: @MonicaCellio [tag:plotting] is ready for you.  There were 9 questions that used it.  I edited 2 of them.  The remaining 7 still have [tag:plotting].  Please merge [tag:plotting] with [tag:plot].  My preference is to get rid of [tag:plotting] altogether (since it has a meaning with data) but if you wish it to be a synonym of [tag:plot] I won't object.

Comment: @aCVn and Monica please let us know what more we can do to prep this for you.  The idea is not to ask the mods to do all the work, just the work that really needs to be done by you.  We want to save you work!  Everything is ready to go.  Let us know if you have questions.  Thanks!

Comment: @Cyn illustrations, diagrams, and screenshots are done (with synonyms).  Plotting is done (without a synonym).  If I missed something, please let me know.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks!  Can you delete [tag:images]?  Everything else looks perfect.  I added some wiki for [tag:book-cover].

Comment: @Cyn we can't, but with no questions it'll be cleaned up by some automatic process soon.  (I *think* that's nightly.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ah okay.  I didn't know how that worked.

Comment: Looks like [tag:images] is now deleted. cc @MonicaCellio